# Powerset of an HList of Options

Tags: scala, implicit, shapeless, implicits

I am playing around with Shapeless and I am trying to compute the (kind-of) [powerset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) of an `HList` of `Option`s. Basically, I want to interpret the `HList` as a set, in which case the `Option` value of an element tells me it belongs to the set or not.

For example, given `Some(5) :: Some("a") :: HNil`, I want to obtain the following `HList`s:

```
Some(5) :: Some("a") :: HNil
Some(5) :: None :: HNil
None :: Some("a") :: HNil
None :: None :: HNil
```

I tried the following:

```
object test2 extends Poly2{
  implicit def someA[A,B <: HList] : Case.Aux[Some[A], List[B], List[Option[A] :: B]] = at{(a, hls) =>
    val x: List[Option[A] :: B] = hls.flatMap{ hl =>
      List(
        a :: hl,
        None :: hl
      )
    }
    x
  }
  implicit val none : Case.Aux[None.type, List[HList], List[HList]] = at{(_, hls) =>
    hls.map(hl => None :: hl)
  }
}

h.foldRight(List(HNil))(test2)
```

Without success. I get a failed implicit resolution at the `foldRight`:

```
Error:(36, 25) could not find implicit value for parameter folder: shapeless.ops.hlist.RightFolder[Some[Int] :: None.type :: shapeless.HNil,List[shapeless.HNil.type],A$A8.this.test2.type]
h.foldRight(List(HNil))(test2);}
                       ^
```

I am starting to think that what I want is not possible/makes no sense in Shapeless, because `Some[A]` and `None` are different types, and I am trying to mix them like they were not (e.g. the `List[Option[A] :: B]` in `someA`), but I would be very happy to be proven wrong. :)

**Update to initial question:**

Thanks to @Marth's comment, I realized that my code worked fine, **as long as I did not use IntelliJ Scala Worksheet**! I used a plain `object` and it worked.
Also, I neeed to add a case to the `Poly` for `Option[A]`. The final code is the following:

```
object combine1 extends Poly2{
    implicit def optionA[A,B <: HList] : Case.Aux[Option[A], List[B], List[Option[A] :: B]] = at{(a, hls) =>
      val x: List[Option[A] :: B] = hls.flatMap{ hl => a match {
          case Some(_) =>
            List(
              None :: hl,
              a :: hl,
            )
          case None =>
            List(None :: hl)
        }
      }
      x
    }

    implicit def someA[A,B <: HList] : Case.Aux[Some[A], List[B], List[Option[A] :: B]] = at{(a, hls) =>
      val x: List[Option[A] :: B] = hls.flatMap{ hl =>
        List(
          None :: hl,
          a :: hl
        )
      }
      x
    }

    implicit val none : Case.Aux[None.type, List[HList], List[HList]] = at{(_, hls) =>
      hls.map(hl => None :: hl)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Unless I missed something your example seems to run fine: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/HWu7dkRKQUmDWClUehuTvQ ?

Comment: Actually, yes. IntelliJ's Scala Worksheet was apparently misbehaving. I tried adding the same code in an `object` and it worked as expected.... Thanks for making me think of that! :) If you want to add your comment as an answer, I will accept it.