# HList foldRight is working, but foldLeft does not compile

Tags: scala, implicit, shapeless

This is a follow up on [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47158613/powerset-of-an-hlist-of-options).

So, I am trying to compute the (kind-of) [powerset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) of an HList of Options. Basically, I want to interpret the HList as a set, in which case the Option value of an element tells me it belongs to the set or not.

I was able to do what I need with the following code:

```
object combine1 extends Poly2{
    implicit def optionA[A,B <: HList] : Case.Aux[Option[A], List[B], List[Option[A] :: B]] = at{(a, hls) =>
      val x: List[Option[A] :: B] = hls.flatMap{ hl => a match {
          case Some(_) =>
            List(
              None :: hl,
              a :: hl,
            )
          case None =>
            List(None :: hl)
        }
      }
      x
    }

    implicit def someA[A,B <: HList] : Case.Aux[Some[A], List[B], List[Option[A] :: B]] = at{(a, hls) =>
      val x: List[Option[A] :: B] = hls.flatMap{ hl =>
        List(
          None :: hl,
          a :: hl
        )
      }
      x
    }

    implicit val none : Case.Aux[None.type, List[HList], List[HList]] = at{(_, hls) =>
      hls.map(hl => None :: hl)
    }
  }
```

All this works fine with `foldRight`:

```
val h1 = Some(2) :: none[BigDecimal] :: Some("b") :: HNil
h1.foldRight(List(HNil))(combine1).foreach(println)
```

Prints:

```
// None :: None :: None :: HNil
// Some(2) :: None :: None :: HNil
// None :: None :: Some(b) :: HNil
// Some(2) :: None :: Some(b) :: HNil
```

However, **`foldLeft` does not work**. Why is that?

```
h1.foldLeft(List(HNil))(combine1).foreach(println)
```

Results in the following:

```
Error:(72, 26) could not find implicit value for parameter folder: shapeless.ops.hlist.LeftFolder[Some[Int] :: Some[Unit] :: Some[String] :: shapeless.HNil,List[shapeless.HNil.type],swaps.tec.util.Experiment.combine1.type]
```

What am I missing?

*N.B. I know that to use `foldLeft` I will eventually need to reverse each `HList` to get the same results as for `foldRight`, but right now I am only interested in actually left-folding the initial `HList`. I will fix the out output once I get one :)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FoldLeft takes arguments in a different order. You should define `Case.Aux[List[B], Option[A], ...]`.

[image: foldr]

[image: foldl]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)

Comment: Well, I could have swore I tried that, but clearly I did not. That did indeed solved my problem. Thanks